# Procedure to determine the equality of numbers in rationals plus square root

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

Consider the set $\mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$ of real numbers that can be constructed by applying finitely many of the five operations $+$, $-$, $\cdot$, $/$ and $\sqrt{}$ to a positive rational number. Examples would be $\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3}$ or $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}-3$.

I would like to find a procedure (an algorithm) which determines of a given number in $\mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$ if it is zero or not.

If it is impossible to give such a procedure, I would like to know why.

Comment: There is such an algorithm. An overkill way to see this is to use the fact that the theory of real closed fields is [complete and decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination).

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you. Is there a less "overkill" version which allows me to really write down the algorithm?

Comment: You may get a polynomial with integer coefficients for which this number is a root (recursion on the depth of square roots tree). Then separate its roots and calculate your number with enough precision.

Comment: An upper bound on the complexity of the problem is given by the existential theory of the reals, which is in PSPACE. I don't think anything better is known; IIRC, it is an open problem if there is a polynomial algorithm to test an inequality between two sums of square roots of integers.

Comment: By the way, $\mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$ is the field of numbers that can be constructed using a compass and a ruler.

Comment: For the $\sqrt{}$, are you assuming the radicand is always positive, and that the root will always be the positive one?

Comment: @user44191 Always the positive one.

Comment: @Wojowu this field has irreducible polynomials of degree 3, so is not real closed.

Comment: Before asking whether there's a procedure to determine whether a given number in this field is zero, you need to describe how to input such numbers. An input would be a certain composition of the given operations, and it should be ensured that expressions in the radicals are already positive, which assumes that one can determine algorithmically that it is the case.

Comment: @YCor do you need to assume that you can determine that all radicands are positive algorithmically, rather than providing an algorithm that's guaranteed to work as long as all radicands are positive (and may have arbitrary behavior in other circumstances)?

Comment: @YCor I know, but if an equality holds in this field, then it holds in $\mathbb R$ and vice versa, so we can reduce it to a question in a real closed field.

Comment: The answer is **yes**: more generally, there exist algorithms to perform exact computations on real algebraic numbers (i.e., compute their sums, differences, products, quotients, roots of polynomials, and perform comparisons for equality and order): see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/302227/17064) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/116077/17064) for closely related answers, and references.

Comment: And I should add that, in sage, if you write something like `QQbar(sqrt(2+sqrt(2))*sqrt(2-sqrt(2))) == QQbar(sqrt(2))` and it returns `True` (resp. `False`), this is a proof of equality (resp. non-equality), barring, of course, any bugs in Sage.

Comment: @Wojowu I don't think this answers the question. This is a algorithmic question whose input is sequence of symbols defining an element of this field.

Comment: @YCor The same sequence of symbols  defines an element of $\mathbb R$. The question of whether this element is zero can be expressed in the language of the theory of real closed fields and, by completeness, algorithmically decided.

Comment: @YCor I have given a more detailed explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've decided to write up my answer given in the comments in details. The main tool I am going to use is [decidability of the theory of real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination), and the fact $\mathbb R$ is a real closed field. What this means that if we are given a sentence in the first-order language of ordered fields (i.e. using $0,1$, addition, multiplication, inequality and quantifiers over numbers), we can algorithmically decide whether it's true in $\mathbb R$ or not.

That said, it's enough to give a procedure which, given some expression involving $+,-,\cdot,/,\sqrt{}$, will give us a formula which expresses whether it's zero. I will explain this through an example. Take $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}-3$, the example from question.

- $\sqrt{2}$ is defined as $x_1$ satisfying $x_1\cdot x_1=1+1\land x_1>0$.
- $3+\sqrt{2}$ is defined as $x_2$ satisfying $\exists x_1:(x_2=1+1+1+x_1\land(x_1^2=1+1\land x_1>0))$
- $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}$ is defined as $x_3$ satisfying $\exists x_2:\left(\exists x_1:(x_2=1+1+1+x_1\land(x_1^2=1+1\land x_1>0))\land x_3\cdot x_3=x_2\land x_3>0\right)$
- $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}-3$ is defined as $x_4$ satisfying $\exists x_3:\left(\exists x_2:\left(\exists x_1:(x_2=1+1+1+x_1\land(x_1^2=1+1\land x_1>0))\land x_3\cdot x_3=x_2\land x_3>0\right)\land x_3=x_4+1+1+1\right)$
- Finally, $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}-3=0$ is expressed as $\exists x_4:\left(\exists x_3:\left(\exists x_2:\left(\exists x_1:(x_2=1+1+1+x_1\land(x_1^2=1+1\land x_1>0))\\\land x_3\cdot x_3=x_2\land x_3>0\right)\land x_3=x_4+1+1+1\right)\land x_4=0\right)$

I hope the idea here is clear - we inductively give definitions for each subexpression, and then we state the element given by the final definition is equal to zero. It should be clear enough this translation can be done algorithmically, and hence equality of such expressions to zero can be algorithmically decided.

Let me make a quick note on practicality of this algorithm: it's nowhere near practical. Appealing to full decidability of theory of real closed fields is a major overkill. As you can read in the Wikipedia page linked above, the algorithm for deciding full theory is necessarily doubly exponential, so for the formula above, which is about 30 characters long, this would give us a bound on running time which is on the order of $2^{2^{30}}$, which is a number with 300 million digits!

However, the formulas we derive above are not some generic formulas - they are *existential*, i.e. don't involve any universal quantifiers. For those formulas there is an algorithm with exponential running time - faster, but still impractical, even for small formulas, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals) for details.

In conclusion, this gives us that that the problem is solvable *in principle*. *In practice*, other algorithms are needed.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: Suppose the algorithmic translation is applied to an illegitimate expression, such as $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{3}}$. Then the final formula is false, since at least one (and so the leftmost) existential quantifier cannot be satisfied. So if we apply the decision algorithm to an expression for a putative $x \in \mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$, and it returns false, it could be either that $x \in \mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$ is non-zero, or that the expression is illegitimate. By definition, elements of $\mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$ have legitimate expressions, so no problem. But can such expressions be recognised algorithmically?

Comment: @MarkWildon This amounts to checking that every partial expression, when under a square root, is positive. This can be checked in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for even for complex $x$. The assumption is that an expression of $x$ of the prescribed form is given, and that there is a sign convention for the root that can be checked algorithmically (see below).

Any given such number $x$ lies in a finite extension field $K$ of $\mathbb Q$. Construct a basis of K and express $x$ in this basis to see whether $x=0$.

OK, so how to construct $K$? That can be done iteratively, following the expression of $x$.  Let $K_0=\mathbb Q$, then adjoin roots as needed. In your example then, $K_1=K_0[z_1]/(z_1^2-2)$ and $K_2=K_1[z_2]/(z_2^2-(3 + z_1))$. At this step, one needs to check that $z_2^2-(3 + z_1)$ is irreducible over $K_1$.

In this special case, one simply needs to check whether $y^2-(3 + z_1)$ has a zero $y\in K_1$.  This is a system of two quadratic equations in two indeterminates. It is zero-dimensional, since a quadratic equation over the field $K_1$ has at most two solutions. Thus, one can use Gröbner bases with respect to an elimination order to check for a rational solution.  (There might be a more elegant algorithm to check irreducibility, but I don't know.)

At last, one checks whether $z_2-3=0$ in $K_2$.

It remains to describe in more detail the reducible case. Suppose that at step $i$ we want to adjoin square root of $p\in K_{i-1}$. If $z_{i}^2-p$ is reducible, then $K_{i-1}$ contains two roots of $p$ (or one of $p=0$). Choose the one that conforms to your *sign convention* of $\sqrt{}$ and replace $\sqrt{p}$ by this root in the expression of $x$.

So how to single out the correct root? Usually, the square root is defined uniquely by a sign condition on real and imaginary part. I guess there should be a similar iterative algorithm that allows to check such sign conditions. An alternative would be to check this sign condition numerically. Of course, then one might ask: why bother at all, why not just try to answer the original question by numerical evaluation? One reason might be that verifying numerically whether something is zero is extremely difficult, while verifying numerically whether something is positive is relatively easy.

Comment: Showing that every element of a countable field belongs to some field in which it is computable does not mean that the given field is computable. Every finitely generated field is computable. Maybe the point is that the finitely generated subfield can be constructed algorithmically according to the given element (or rather the given expression in terms of radicals).